# Does it make sense to use optimization algorithms(Like ACO) in weighing average to find weighs

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I am going to use a DEM fusion method using simple weighing average,I am going to use 2 inputs to create my fusion function `W1X1+W2X2/(w1+W2)=result` this is a simple weighing average but I want to use optimization algorithms like ant colony to find w1 and w2.
I want to minimize the distance between result and real data by using ACO,I mean some how I want to minimize this function `E=Sigma((result-realdata)^2)` 
Does it make any sense ?I mean is it true and there is not better method instead of using optimization algorithms?In fact one of my friend said we don't use ACO and similar algorithms for this simple functions and we must have more than two variables (w1,w2..wn) and then we can use ACO algorithms.Does he right?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understand, you want to fit, in the least-square sense, a model $$Y=\frac{w_1X_1+w_2X_2}{w_1+w_2}$$ You must notice that this model is undetermined since you could mutliply the $w_i$'s by any number and get the same result.

Rewrite the model as  $$Y=\frac{w_1X_1}{w_1+w_2}+\frac{w_2X_2}{w_1+w_2}=\alpha X_1+\beta X_2=\alpha X_1+(1-\alpha) X_2=X_2+\alpha(X_1-X_2)$$ which makes $$Y-X_ 2=\alpha(X_1-X_2)$$ and you are taken to the linear regression through the origin.

Now, for the case of more $X_i$'s, let us consider as the simplest$$Y=\frac{w_1X_1+w_2X_2+w_3X_3}{w_1+w_2+w_3}$$ and let us do the same; it will become $$Y=\alpha X_1+\beta X_2+(1-\alpha-\beta) X_3=X_3+\alpha (X_1-X_3)+\beta (X_2-X3)$$ that is to say $$Y-X_ 3=\alpha(X_1-X_3)+\beta(X_2-X_3)$$ and you are back to standard multilinear regression with no intercept.

For making life easier, define $Z=Y-X_3$, $T=X_1-X_3$, $U=X_2-X_3$).

You really do not need any optimization method for this task. Just do it with Excel.

Comment: Hello,Thank you very much for your great answer,I am somehow forced to use Optimization methods.So I should increase the number of variables to achieve that?

Comment: No. Define your objective function $$E=\sum_{i=1}^n\big(result_i-realdata_i)^2)$$ for which you can provide, if you want, the analytical Jacobian, and run the optimizer with the kind of variables I wrote; it will converge very fast since the function is quadratic. By the way, you are very welcome ! Cheers.